# R plotting PCA scores with ggbiplot

Tags: r, pca, ggbiplot

I'm trying to plot PCA scores using ggbiplot but I can't due to a mismatch between my scores and my groupings. 
I think the mismatch stems from the NA values in my original log-transformed data (which I omit when I calculate the PCs). Is there a way to get around this so that I can plot using ggbiplot?

```
GCelem_trans.pca<-prcomp(na.omit(GCelem_trans.log), center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
GCelem.rxtp <- GCelem[, 9]


g <- ggbiplot(GCelem_trans.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, 
                  groups = GCelem.rxtp, ellipse = TRUE, 
                  circle = TRUE)
    Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "groups", value = c(2L, 5L, 5L, 2L,  : 
      replacement has 33337 rows, data has 30804
```

Should I recalculate GCelem.rxtp based on a copy of GCelem that omits any rows with NAs?

Comment: I think the error is because you haven't subset `GCelem.rxtp` to match the NA-omitted data. You could find the index of the NA rows and subset `GCelem.rxtp` so that the correct values are removed from this, or you could impute the NAs in the original data (for example with the median of each variable).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
GCelem.rxtp <- GCelem[complete.cases(GCelem_trans.log), 9]
```